# Facebook Auth "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials."

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, facebook-authentication

I have multiple login options for the user to choose from: email, google, and facebook. If Firebase already has the email stored as a user (ie. the user previously signed up with test@gmail.com), an alert that tells the user that an account with that email already exists. This works perfectly for Google sign in, as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwYYz.png). However, nothing visually happens when the user clicks the Facebook button (doesn't even switch screens), and I get this error in the debugger:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17012 "An account already exists with
the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a
provider associated with this email address." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL,
FIRAuthErrorUserInfoEmailKey=318junkjabr@gmail.com,
FIRAuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey=<FIROAuthCredential:
0x6000005f3200>, NSLocalizedDescription=An account already exists with the
same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a
provider associated with this email address.}
```

This is my code for the Log In View Controller:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setUpFBButton()
        setUpGoogleButton()
        setUpEmailButton()
            
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    }
    
    
    
// MARK: - SIGN UP WITH GOOGLE
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully logged into Google")
        
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        // sign user in with Firebase
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            let firstName = user?.user.displayName
            let email = user?.user.email
            let lastName = ""
            let uid = user?.user.uid
            
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            } else {
                // Successfully logged in
                print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google email: ", email ?? "", "Now add user to Firestore if user is new.")
                
                // check if user already exists
                self.addUserToFirestore(firstName ?? "", lastName, email ?? "", uid ?? "", "Google")
                    }
                })
            }
    
            
        fileprivate func setUpGoogleButton() {
            Utilities.styleLightFilledButton(signInGoogleButton)
            signInGoogleButton!.addTarget(self, action:
                                #selector(handleCustomGoogleSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
            }
        
        @objc func handleCustomGoogleSignIn() {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
            }
    
    
    
    
// MARK: - SIGN UP WITH FACEBOOK
    
    // design the facebook button and assign #selector to facebook button actions
    fileprivate func setUpFBButton() {
        Utilities.styleHollowButton(signInFacebookButton)
        
        signInFacebookButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomFBButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    // handle the facebook button actions
    @objc func handleCustomFBButton() {
        LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { (result, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Custom FB login failed:", err!)
                return
            }
            self.getUserInfo()
        }
    }
    
    // grab id, name, and email of user
    func getUserInfo() {
        print("Successfully logged in with facebook...")
        GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start {
            (connection, result, err) in
            guard let Info = result as? [String: Any] else { return }
                let name = Info["name"] as? String
                let email = Info["email"] as? String
                let uid = Info["id"] as? String
            
            if err != nil {
                print("Failed to start graph request:", err!)
                return
            }
            print(result!)
            self.signIntoFirebase(name ?? "", email ?? "", uid ?? "")
            
        }
    }
    
    // connect the user to firebase
    func signIntoFirebase(_ name:String, _ email:String, _ uid:String) {
           let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err)
                    return
                } else {
            print("Facebook user successfully authenticated with Firebase. Now run through Firestore.")
            // check if user already exists. if user exists, go to chats screen. if it does not exist, create a new user and redirect to chat screen.
                    self.addUserToFirestore(name, "", email, uid, "Facebook")
                    
                }
            }
        }
    
    
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
        print("Logged out of facebook")
    }
    
    
    
// MARK: - Other functions
    
    func addUserToFirestore(_ firstName:String, _ lastName:String, _ email:String, _ uid:String, _ signInMethod:String) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
        // check if user exists in firestore
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document {
               if document.exists {
                let message = "Good news! You already have a Coal account that uses " + email + ".\nPlease sign in to your existing account. Then you will be able to link your " + signInMethod + " profile from your Account Settings page."
                // user exists. send to chats screen.
                print("User already exists. Document data: \(String(describing: document.data()))")
                self.showError("You're already a member!", message)
              } else {
                // user does not exist. create a new user
                 print("Document does not exist. Create new user.")
                
                docRef.setData(["firstname":firstName, "lastname":lastName, "email":email]) { err in
                    if err != nil {
                        // Show error message
                        print("Error saving user data to Firestore")
                    } else {
                        print("New user created in Firestore")
                        self.transitionToConvo()
                    }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showError(_ title:String, _ message:String) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func transitionToConvo() {
        let tabBarC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController") as! TabBarController
        tabBarC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(tabBarC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Switched to TabBarController")
    }
    
    func setUpEmailButton() {
        Utilities.styleDarkFilledButton(signInEmailButton)
    }
    
    
} // end
```

I think the reason why it's not getting an alert is because the Facebook uid doesn't match the email uid saved in Firestore (while Google uid does match). The way I'm getting the alert to show up is if the uid matches that in Firestore, so consequently, the alert doesn't show. Does anyone know how I can get the alert to show an how to not get this error?

I know my code is a bit messy, so please let me know if you need further explanation. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Did you enable `multi-provider` sign up for users? i.e, in firebase console, allowing users to sign in with facebook and gmail, using the same email address?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying to figure out my problem, I decided to post a question... but almost immediately after, found the answer (i know right :/).

Since one account per email is already enabled in the project settings, `Auth.auth().signIn` automatically scans if a user exists. If a user exists, it'll return an error after `if error != nil`. Because it returned an error before my `addUserToFirestore` function was called (to check if the user exists and if not, add user to Firestore), the alert was never shown.

Now that we know what `if error != nil` means, we can just insert the alert there:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    let message = "Good news! You already have a Coal account that uses " + email + ".\nPlease sign in to your existing account. Then you will be able to link your Facebook profile from your Account Settings page."
                    // user exists. send to chats screen.
                    print("User already exists. Let user know.")
                    self.showError("You're already a member!", message)
                    return
                }
```

I'm not sure why it worked for Google Auth, but it ended up that this is what worked for Facebook Auth.